# FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "pg_username" with pg_ident.conf settings

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-14, pg-hba.conf

I have two DB servers located on host1 and host2, for example

Settings in pg_ident.conf on host2

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
mymap           system_username        pg_username
```

Settings in pg_ident.conf on host1

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
mymap           system_username        pg_username
```

Settings in pg_hba.conf on host1

```
# TYPE  DATABASE                USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
...
local   dbname                    pg_username                       peer map=mymap
....

host    dbname                    pg_username       all             ident map=mymap
```

Also I reloaded configuration:

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

Then, i trying to connect on database (local connection) from host1

```
ssh system_username@host1
psql -p 5432 -U pg_username -d dbname
```

And it's working

But, when I try to connect on database (remote connection to host1) from host2

```
ssh system_username@host2
psql -h host1 -p 5432 -U pg_username -d dbname
```

I got the error

```
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "pg_username" with pg_ident.conf settings
```

At the logs I have:

```
2023-12-07 11:01:47.062 +05 [26328-1] LOG:  could not connect to Ident server at address "host1", port 113: Connection refused
2023-12-07 11:01:47.062 +05 [26328-1] FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "pg_username"
2023-12-07 11:01:47.062 +05 [26328-1] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 104: "host   dbname                    pg_username       all             ident map=mymap"
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: Look in the log file.  It will tell *why* ident authentication failed, rather than just the mere fact that it did.

Comment: @jjanes I added an error from the log to the question (no new information for me)

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't start the ident service.

Don't ever use `ident` authentication for remote connections. It is totally unsafe. With `ident` authentication, the PostgreSQL server asks the ident server on the *client* side about the identity of the user. So if you control the client machine, you can fake any identity you want. `ident` is only trustworthy if the client machine is trustworthy, and then you might as well use `trust`.

Imagine this dialog:

- **Client:** Let me in!
- **Server:** Client machine, what is the operating system user that made the connection request I just got?
- **Ident server on the client machine**: That is a totally trusted user.
- **Server:** Ok, cool, then you can connect without a password.

If you want password-less connections from a remote machine, use a secure authentication method that does not rely on a password, like TLS certificates.

Comment: How can I start ident service?

If I log into the host as user system_username and enter a password, then I can log in without a password as user pg_username in the database (if I have settings in pg_ident.conf), isn't this more secure than using the trust method?

Comment: I understand, but host2 isn't client, it is another DB server. Is this secure if i add in pg_hba.conf:

host    dbname                    pg_username       <host2>             ident map=mymap

Comment: Just as sure as `trust`, yes. So not sure at all.